# How to make the line translucent?

Tags: java, libgdx

Using the rectLine () function, I draw a regular line. I want to make it translucent. The alpha channel is responsible for transparency. I change it using delta time. Nothing happens. What am I doing wrong?

```
if(str.trans > 0) 
rend.setColor(1,1,1,str.trans);

str.trans -= 0.5*delta;

if(str.trans < 0)
iter.remove();
else 
str.renderLine(rend);
```

Comment: What is class the for `rend` ?

Comment: The 4 channels expect `int`. Check if 0.5 * delta always gives you 0 after multiplication.

Comment: @user3437460 OK, then how do transparency change smoothly?

Comment: We can't know if the four channels expect float or int because we don't know what type of object `rend` is.

Comment: @Tenfour04 its ShapeRenderer

Comment: @lalalend `ShapreRenderer.setColor(float r, float g, float b, float a)` uses float so you can continue to use an expression to derive the alpha channel value. But just ensure your expression is correct (e.g. the result will not always be zero)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to enable drawing transparent shapes using the Gdx.gl configuration.

```
Gdx.gl.glEnable(GL20.GL_BLEND);
Gdx.gl.glBlendFunc(GL20.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL20.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

// now you can draw transparent shapes
startDrawingShapes();

Gdx.gl.glDisable(GL20.GL_BLEND);
```